# Subtracting two lists but the values are not adding up in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to perform the operation: `roll_all-theta_all`. Both of them are `lists` containing two values each and the result is supposed to be listed in the column named 'roll' on my `panda.DataFrame`. However when I do so, the 2nd row value of column 'roll' does not add up. Although it cannot be seen because I perform `theta_all` operation in other parts of my code, I obtain the values the same way I obtain the values of `roll_all`, i.e., by creating an empty `list` and then append the values to it. Here is my code:

```
pyr = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['pitch','yaw','roll'])

for para in GTparas:  
    Mr = np.array([[np.cos(para[2]), -np.sin(para[2]), 0],[np.sin(para[2]), np.cos(para[2]), 0],[0, 0, 1]])
    My = np.array([[np.cos(para[1]), 0, np.sin(para[1])],[0, 1, 0],[-np.sin(para[1]), 0, np.cos(para[1])]])
    Mp = np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, np.cos(para[0]), -np.sin(para[0])],[0, np.sin(para[0]), np.cos(para[0])]])
    M1 = np.dot(Mr,My)
    M = np.dot(M1,Mp)

    pitch = np.arctan(M[2,1]/M[2,2])
    yaw = np.arctan(M[2,0]/((((M[0,0])**2)+((M[1,0])**2))**(1/2)))
    roll = np.arctan(M[1,0]/M[0,0])
    
    roll_all = []
    roll_all.append(roll)
    print(roll_all)
    c = [a - b for a, b in zip(roll_all, theta_all)]
    #c = np.array(roll_all) - np.array(theta_all)
  
    pyr = pyr.append({'pitch':pitch,'yaw':yaw,'roll':c},ignore_index = True) # from Z-Y-X to X-Y-Z
print(pyr)
```

I am also attaching the values in my lists for `theta_all` and the second image shows the values in `roll_all` and what I get when I print `pyr`.

[image: values of theta_all]
[image: values of theta_all and pyr]

Comment: But you empty out `roll_all` during each loop, so it always has exactly one item in it.  There is never a second item.  I suspect you want `roll_all = []` before the loop, and the last four lines to be outdented so it's not part of the loop.  Maybe.

Comment: If I put `roll_all = []` out of the loop then for each iteration I do get the new values but they are repeated, so I get these new values when I print `roll_all`: `[-0.22244452195971454]` and `[-0.22244452195971454,-1.5364830969300616]`. And `pyr` has to remain in the loop because I am obtaining the other values for `pitch` and `yaw` which are added iteratively

Comment: OK, fine, but where do you think `roll_all` is getting 2 values?

Comment: Well I am not using `roll_all` anywhere else in my code. If `roll_all = []` is kept out of the loop I understand that for each iteration each value and past values are stored in that array. Now if `roll_all=[]` is inside the loop (as I have done) then for each iteration I only add the new value, which is what I need, but the problem actually lies when I subtract `theta_all` from `roll_all` because if you work it out manually row1 of 'roll' should be `-0.037589514`

Comment: You're producing -0.222444 for roll in the first iteration.  The subtraction is going to do `roll_all[0] - theta_all[0]`, which gives 1.31597, as it says.  It will never use `theta_all[1]`, because there will never be a `roll_all[1].`.   OK?

Comment: I do understand that, and it is fine that result is good. I was referring to the other row whereby I am getting 0.001938. Whereas in actual fact it should be, or at least I need it to be, -0.037589514.

Comment: No, in the second iteration it's still going to be `roll_all[0] - theta_all[0]`, which is -1.53648+1.538431, which is 0.00193819.  If you want `theta_all` to change for each iteration, maybe you need to do `for para,theta in zip(GTparams,theta_all):`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I changed the second line of my code as you said, and I obtained for 'roll' the first row: `1.3159` and for the 2nd row: `1.3159`, `-0.0375`. This result I had already obtained by placing `roll_all=[]` out of the loop. Would you know of a way to only obtain `-0.0375` for the second row?

Comment: roll_all[] does not need to be a list at all.  Just say `roll_all  = roll - theta` and use it as a single value.

Comment: Thank you tim for your assistance that worked as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing:

```
pyr = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['pitch','yaw','roll'])

for para,theta in zip(GTparas, theta_all):
    Mr = np.array([[np.cos(para[2]), -np.sin(para[2]), 0],[np.sin(para[2]), np.cos(para[2]), 0],[0, 0, 1]])
    My = np.array([[np.cos(para[1]), 0, np.sin(para[1])],[0, 1, 0],[-np.sin(para[1]), 0, np.cos(para[1])]])
    Mp = np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, np.cos(para[0]), -np.sin(para[0])],[0, np.sin(para[0]), np.cos(para[0])]])
    M1 = np.dot(Mr,My)
    M = np.dot(M1,Mp)

    pitch = np.arctan(M[2,1]/M[2,2])
    yaw = np.arctan(M[2,0]/((((M[0,0])**2)+((M[1,0])**2))**(1/2)))
    roll = np.arctan(M[1,0]/M[0,0]) - theta
      
    pyr = pyr.append({'pitch':pitch,'yaw':yaw,'roll':roll},ignore_index = True) 

print(pyr)
```